# importing d3.event into a custom build using rollup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollupjs

I've got a file `d3.custom.build.js` like this (simplified):

```
import { range } from 'd3-array';
import { select, selectAll, event } from 'd3-selection';
import { transition } from 'd3-transition';

export default {
    range,
    select,
    selectAll,
    event,
    transition
};
```

And a `rollup.config.js` like this:

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
    entry: './js/vendor/d3-custom-build.js',
    dest: './js/vendor/d3-custom-built.js',
    format: 'iife',
    globals: {
        d3: 'd3'
    },
    moduleId: 'd3',
    moduleName: 'd3',
    plugins: [nodeResolve({ jsnext: true })]
};
```

I want to export to a plain old browser global named 'd3'. I'm calling rollup from a simple npm script. The good news is that almost everything works in the output file, except for one thing: `d3.event` in browser is always null. No, it's not an issue with events being hijacked on the page. When I swap in the standard full d3 4.0 library into the script tag everything works fine. It's definitely a build issue.

The [d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#customEvent) warn that bundling `event` is tricky:

> If you use Babel, Webpack, or another ES6-to-ES5 bundler, be aware
>   that the value of d3.event changes during an event! An import of
>   d3.event must be a live binding, so you may need to configure the
>   bundler to import from D3’s ES6 modules rather than from the generated
>   UMD bundle; not all bundlers observe jsnext:main. Also beware of
>   conflicts with the window.event global.

It appears that setting `nodeResolve({ jsnext: true })` isn't sufficing. How do I get a live binding in the bundle? Any guidance very appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You’re exporting an object, defined using ES2015 shorthand object literal syntax, as the default export. Here is the long form equivalent of what you’ve written:

```
export default {
  range: range,
  select: select,
  selectAll: selectAll,
  event: event,
  transition: transition
}
```

Your object thus captures the value of `event` on load, which is null; it is not a live binding, and won’t reflect the current event.

One fix would be to define the `event` property using a getter:

```
export default {
  range,
  select,
  selectAll,
  get event() { return event; },
  transition
}
```

Better would be to use named exports instead of a default export, and then Rollup will generate a live binding automatically:

```
export {
  range,
  select,
  selectAll,
  event,
  transition
}
```

This is not only shorter, but now you don’t depend on the browser supporting the ES2015 shorthand object literal syntax.

Comment: that makes sense for exporting the event itself, however I am facing the same issue but am only using an external version of d3 in my rollup. So how then do I circumvent the issue?

Comment: Why does rollup generate a live binding automatically?

Comment: Possibly related rollup issue on github: [Default import/export is not treated as live binding](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1078)

Comment: The [blog post](https://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) explains how live bindings are supposed to work.