# d3.event not working when combining modules

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, webpack

I have a code where I'm importing (es6 `import` statement) d3-selection and d3-transition.  However I also need to capture event.  When I don't import d3-transition the d3.events works perfectly.  As soon as I import d3-transition I get an error stating that `d3.event` is `null` and cannot reference event properties.

There is a note in the D3 API Reference.

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event: 
*If you use Babel, Webpack, or another ES6-to-ES5 bundler, be aware that the value of d3.event changes during an event! An import of d3.event must be a live binding, so you may need to configure the bundler to import from D3’s ES6 modules rather than from the generated UMD bundle; not all bundlers observe jsnext:main. Also beware of conflicts with the window.event global.*

I'm using babel (for ie11 support) and webpack for bundling.  What does this note mean?  Why doesn't something like `import {event as d3event} from'd3-selection';` followed by `let d3 = Object.assign({}, d3selection, d3transition, d3event};` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {event as d3event} from'd3-selection'
d3event === null // true; `event`'s value changes later with user input.
let d3 = Object.assign({}, d3selection, d3transition, d3event)
// won't have an `event` property since Object.assign({}, null) -> {}
```

Adding `d3.event = event // or d3 = {event}` will still return the null event observed at assignment time; see [Mike Bostock's method of getting the current event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40048292/6571327) for a solution.

[The d3.event note](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event) now contains [a link](http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html#es6-modules-export-immutable-bindings) to an explanation of what a live binding is: a reference to a variable within `d3-selection`.

An additional caveat which cost me some time: if `d3-drag` is pointing to a different version of `d3-select` than your other tools, `d3.select(/**/).call(d3.drag(/**/))` won't work, since events never reach the `event` variable that `d3.drag` is using. Somewhere around `d3@^5`, the main package no longer pins the `d3-selection` version, allowing this sort of mismatch.

Comment: This is not an issue anymore as event is not part of `d3-selection anymore`. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029018/d3-version-6-zoom-functionality-not-working-export-event-was-not-found-in-d3#comment113230324_64029018