# d3 version 6 zoom functionality not working."export 'event' was not found in 'd3-selection'

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, angular9, d3-force-directed

I had installed d3Charts using npm install d3 && npm install @types/d3 --save-dev.

d3 version info in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "d3": "^6.1.1",
}
"devDependencies": {
    .....
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
      ....
}
```

Below is the code snippet.
Chart is coming up properly only getting issues with zoom functionality.

**Error:"export 'event' was not found in 'd3-selection'**

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

      let transform = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(200, 0).scale(1);
      let zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5,10]).on("zoom", handleZoom);

  function handleZoom() {
          if ( svg ) {
              svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
          }
```

Under @types, checked the index.d.ts

```
export * from 'd3-array';
export * from 'd3-axis';
export * from 'd3-brush';
export * from 'd3-chord';
export * from 'd3-collection';
export * from 'd3-color';
export * from 'd3-contour';
export * from 'd3-dispatch';
export * from 'd3-drag';
export * from 'd3-dsv';
export * from 'd3-ease';
export * from 'd3-fetch';
export * from 'd3-force';
export * from 'd3-format';
export * from 'd3-geo';
export * from 'd3-hierarchy';
export * from 'd3-interpolate';
export * from 'd3-path';
export * from 'd3-polygon';
export * from 'd3-quadtree';
export * from 'd3-random';
export * from 'd3-scale';
export * from 'd3-scale-chromatic';
export * from 'd3-selection';
export * from 'd3-shape';
export * from 'd3-time';
export * from 'd3-time-format';
export * from 'd3-timer';
export * from 'd3-transition';
export * from 'd3-voronoi';
export * from 'd3-zoom';
```

Comment: I also encountered many d3 type error with `@types/d3`.

Comment: `d3.event` no longer exists as [part of D3v6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/7106086), the event is now the first parameter passed to the event listener function - something like: `function handleZoom(event) { svg.attr("transform",event.transform; })`. I believe this is the source of your error.