# Rollup d3 mouse no longer works?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollupjs

So I have a function which uses d3 that I have rolled up, which correspondingly has a `mousemove` event

in essence, I want the mouse position relative to the page so I call something like:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3'

...

export function foo() {
  d3.select("html").on('mousemove',()=>{
    console.log(d3.mouse(d3.select('html').node()))
  })
}
```

when this is rolled up I get `current is null`

```
TypeError: current is null
```

the stack trace is my `mousemove` function to `mouse` which points to `sourceEvent`

```js
  function sourceEvent() {
    var current = event, source;
    while (source = current.sourceEvent) current = source;
    return current;
  }
```

thoughts?

## rollup.config.js

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify-es';
import minimist from 'minimist';


import pkg from './package.json';

const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

const config = {
  input: 'src/entry.js',

  output: {
    name: pkg.name,
    exports: 'named',
    extend: true,
    external: ['d3'],
    globals: {
      d3: 'd3'
    },
  },

plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      externalHelpers: true,
    //   runtimeHelpers: true,
    }),
    nodeResolve({
      mainFields: ['module', 'main', 'jsnext']
    }),
    commonjs({
      // non-CommonJS modules will be ignored, but you can also
      // specifically include/exclude files
      include: 'node_modules/**',  // Default: undefined

      // search for files other than .js files (must already
      // be transpiled by a previous plugin!)
      extensions: [ '.js', '.coffee' ],  // Default: [ '.js' ]

      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/d3/dist/d3.node.js': [
          'selection', 'mouse', 'select', 'interpolateRgbBasis',
          'median', 'min', 'max', 'scaleLinear', 'easeExp', 'extent', 'event',
          'easeSin', 'selectAll', 'keys', 'interpolateRgb', 'descending', 'line',
          'curveBasis', 'histogram', 'ascending', 'sourceEvent'
        ],
        // 'node_modules/d3/d3.js': ['selection', 'mouse', 'select'],
        // 'node_modules/d3-selection/src/selection/index.js': ['selection']
      },

      // sometimes you have to leave require statements
      // unconverted. Pass an array containing the IDs
      // or a `id => boolean` function. Only use this
      // option if you know what you're doing!
      ignore: [ 'conditional-runtime-dependency' ]
    })

  ],
  onwarn: function ( message ) {
    if (message.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY') {
      return;
    }
    console.error(message);
  }
};

// Only minify browser (iife) version
if (argv.format === 'iife') {
  config.plugins.push(uglify());
}

export default config;
```

removing `'event'` from `namedExports` yields the rollup event

```
{ code: 'MISSING_EXPORT',
  missing: 'event',
  importer: 'src/modules/legends/numeric-legend.js',
  exporter: 'node_modules/d3/dist/d3.node.js',
  message:
   "'event' is not exported by 'node_modules/d3/dist/d3.node.js'",
  url: 'https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module-',
  ...
}
```

I have also tried adding:

```
export default { 
  ...
  get event() { return event; },
}
```

to my exports but this doesn't work either

Comment: Have you seen [*importing d3.event into a custom build using rollup*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012016/importing-d3-event-into-a-custom-build-using-rollup)?

Comment: @altocumulus I had not. Thank you. However that is for a custom d3 library where exporting event like that to me makes sense. Here I am only exporting a function which is using (or should be using) an external d3. So I am unclear how to correct this

Comment: @altocumulus I added my `rollup.config.js` file if that helps

Comment: @altocumulus any other suggestions or ideas?